# Notepad++ regexp to search and replace with exceptions

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm a regexp newbie and I would like to know how to do a search and replace for the following case:

A file contains many occurrences of the following:

```
L1234_XL3.ext
```

and also many occurrences of:

```
L1234_XL3
```

I only want to find and replace `L1234_XL3` occurrences with `XL3` without affecting instances that have an extension.

I am using notepad++ to do the regular expression.

Comment: Now NP++ supports lookaheads! (v6.1.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Notepad++ supports lookaheads, you can simply use `L1234_XL3(?!\.ext)` for the search and "XL3" for the replacement.

**EDIT:** Looks like it doesn't support lookaheads after all. A pity; you'll have to do it the hard way without regexes (regexen?):

1. Replace L1234_XL3.ext with QQQ (or any other string that doesn't appear in the file)
2. Replace L1234_XL3 with XL3.
3. Replace QQQ with L1234_XL3.ext.

Comment: As pointed out by Gabber, Notepad++ now supports lookaheads, so the regex given here works now.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1.
Change all occurences of L1234_XL3.ext to L-1-2-3-4_XL3.ext (for example)

Step 2.
Change all occurences of L1234_XL3 to XL3

Step 3.
Change all occurences of L-1-2-3-4_XL3.ext back to L1234_XL3.ext

As far as I understand Notepad++ 5.4.5 doesn't support positive lookahead

Comment: yeah thought of this already, but I thought it would be nice to know the regexp.

Comment: You can find out about positive lookahead here : http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html. Although to use it you need an other editor. Personally I use EditPadPro