# Remove special characters between digits up to a limit using regex

Tags: regex, special-characters, notepad++

How do I remove the special characters [  and ] below using regex, while preserving the square brackets at the back of the sentence?

From

```
468620188,[2012-07-07 00:00:00,057],[Thread-20],INFO,BIZ,Handler,getJobs,[Result] Retrieving broadcast []
```

To

```
468620188,2012-07-07 00:00:00,057,Thread-20,INFO,BIZ,Handler,getJobs,[Result] Retrieving broadcast []
```

Comment: what regex engine/language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with perl REs, using a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
s/[\[\]](?=.*,)//g;
```

It removes any `[` or `]` character that has a `,` character somewhere after it.

If you're not using perl, this probably won't be as useful.

---

### EDIT:

This might work:

1. Search for `\[([^\n]*,)`, replace with `\1`.  Hit Replace All
2. Search for `\]([^\n]*,)`, replace with `\1`.  Hit Replace All.

Please note I don't have access to Notepad++ to test this; I'm just going off some screen shots of the search box I found online.

Comment: I'm using notepad++. Sorry, should have mentioned this before. Not familiar with perl at all, am not sure how to convert it.

Comment: @louisxie: It looks like [Notepad++ does not support lookaheads](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2115668/13860). :( You may be out of luck...

Comment: that worked, except I would like to limit it to only the first 2 instance of [ in the sentence. is that possible? Otherwise, I could also perform that twice. It just requires more time to execute, given my file is 7MB large. Let me know! :)

Comment: If I had Notepad++ here to play with, I might be able to come up with something like that... but alas, I don't. :(

Answer (score 0):

In one step it is possible,  but only for your given sample, Try it...

Find:`\[(.*?\d+)\]`
Replace all with: `\1`